# Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools. Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit

Tags: json, ruby, bundler

I'm having trouble building a Ruby project on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using awesome_print 1.7.0
Installing json 2.1.0 with native extensions
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using ffi 1.9.18 (x64-mingw32)
Using rubyzip 1.2.1
Using websocket 1.2.4
Using tomlrb 1.2.4
Using bundler 1.14.6
Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

An error occurred while installing json (2.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '2.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've included both Ruby and the DevKit in my PATH environment variable, i.e. `C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\Ruby-DevKit\bin`. What could be going wrong?

The command I'm running is `bundle install` in the `..\tindermation\node_modules\.bin` directory of this project: https://github.com/feelobot/tindermation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't initialize and bind the ruby installations in my DevKit to my PATH:

Downloaded it, ran it to extract it somewhere (permanent). Then cd to it, run `ruby dk.rb init` and `ruby dk.rb install`. The `bundle install` command worked after following these steps.